# Unable to find System.Windows.Form on Widows Container with dotnet6 installed

Tags: .net-6.0, windows-container, server-core

I have a dotnet6 UnitTest project that tests some code that uses wix. It uses the package `WixToolset.Dft.WindowsInstaller (4.0.4)`. The code that is being tested, will use `MessageBox.Show()` if an exception is thrown.

The use of MessageBox.Show() results in `System.Windows.Forms` to be required.

When I compile and execute the code through visual studio, the tests finish without issue. But when I through my CI pipeline use a Windows Container to execute the tests, I get this error:

> "System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file
> specified."

I am executing other test projects in dotnet6 through the same container. And they complete ust fine.

has `dotnet6.0-windows` defined as `<TargetFramework>`. Is also has `<UseWindowsForms>` & `<UseWPF>` set to `true`

In the Dockerfile we are using a powershell script to download binaries, to be installed, from our artifact storage.

Here's the dockerfile for the container that executes the tests:

```
#start with a download stage
ARG REGISTRY="artifactory.company.com"
FROM ${REGISTRY}/crmd/artifactory-util-windows:1.0.2 AS copystage
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

ARG TOKEN
ARG FOLDER="thirdparty-generic-upload-local/microsoft/"
RUN .\artifactoryDownload.ps1 ${Env:FOLDER}vcredist/vcredist-x64-14.29.30133.0.exe
RUN .\artifactoryDownload.ps1 ${Env:FOLDER}mssql-server/msodbcsql_17.msi
RUN .\artifactoryDownload.ps1 ${Env:FOLDER}mssql-server/MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi
RUN .\artifactoryDownload.ps1 ${Env:FOLDER}dotnet/dotnet-sdk-6.0.402-win-x64.exe

FROM $REGISTRY/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
WORKDIR /

COPY --from=copystage ["vcredist-x64-14.29.30133.0.exe", "VC_redist.x64.exe"]
COPY --from=copystage ["msodbcsql_17.msi", "msodbcsql.msi"] 
COPY --from=copystage ["MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi", "MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi"] 
COPY --from=copystage ["dotnet-sdk-6.0.402-win-x64.exe", "Net6.exe"] 

RUN Start-Process -Wait -FilePath .\VC_redist.x64.exe -ArgumentList '/S','/v','/qn' -passthru
RUN Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "msiexec" -ArgumentList '/i .\msodbcsql.msi','/qn','/L*v msi1.log','IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES' -passthru
RUN Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "msiexec" -ArgumentList '/i .\MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi','/qn','/L*v msi2.log','IACCEPTMSSQLCMDLNUTILSLICENSETERMS=YES' -passthru
RUN Start-Process -Wait -FilePath .\Net6.exe -ArgumentList '/S','/v','/qn' -passthru

RUN rm VC_redist.x64.exe
RUN rm msodbcsql.msi
RUN rm MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi
RUN rm Net6.exe
```

From my point of view, it seems as if `System.Windows.Forms` is for some reason not part of the Windows Container, even though dotnet6 is installed.

What am I missing here? It feels like I'm not seeing the complete picture

Comment: I see the image you are using is the Server Core, which doesn't have any GUI APIs. Have you tried using the Server image? It's MUCH larger, but at least it has the GUI APIs.